# Can I use sass instead of node-sass in suiteCommerce project?

Tags: sass, gulp, netsuite, suitescript, gulp-sass

I am using mac system.

```
chip : apple M2
macOS : Ventura 13.4
```

i was trying to install suiteCommerce Theme Developer Tool, but ran into following problem

when i was trying to install `node-sass v7.0.0`, npm is trying to install package from following url location :
*https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v7.0.0/darwin-arm64-83_binding.node*

[image: Error image]

you can see that in image i have attached, its hitting url that does not exist hence 404 code.
but url for `v7.0.0 (drwin-arm64-83)` has changed to following location :
*https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v7.0.0/darwin-x64-83_binding.node*

***reference:***
*https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v7.0.0*

> this issue has already been raised to node-sass team

***references:***
*https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/3033*
*https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/3407*

**Question is that can i install sass instead of node-sass in my Theme Developer Tool ?**

Answer (score 0):

Use node, say `20.10`. Run npm install. Then `npm uninstall node-sass`. Then `npm install node-sass`. It'll install the version 9.0.0 and you'll be able to run gulp commands.